# Pylons vs Turbogears

Tags: pylons, turbogears2

I am considering whether I should use Turbogears or Pylons for my project. I know Turbogears2 is based on Pylons. What does Turbogears provide that Pylon doesn't?
Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turbogears emphasises integration, while Pylons emphasises modularity -- with TG2, you're getting such components as [genshi](http://genshi.edgewall.org/), [toscawidgets](http://toscawidgets.org/), and [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/), all integrated and coordinated. Of course you could integrate and coordinate each of them (or other templating systems, widget systems, ORMs, etc) with Pylons, but no doubt many people will prefer to get the complete package (and the peace of mind that comes from knowing everything has been tested in that specific version and configuration) rather than getting each piece separately and doing their own integration.

Answer (score 4):

Some time ago I came up with this on IRC:

Imagine you have a puzzle and the picture in the box is a boat out on the sea (yes one of those hard ones).

With Pylons you will start looking at all those blue pieces and putting them together sometimes messing up because you don't know if they are sky or sea.

With TurboGears all the blue is already done and you simply go and work on the ship. But if you are interested in doing some of the blue you go and undo that part of the puzzle and build it again*.

*here the analogy breaks a little as the replacement component doesn't needs to be build out of the same set of pieces :)

Answer (score 0):

neil balkey-milner has a [valuable analysis/comparison](http://nxsy.org/unscientific-and-biased-comparison-of-django-pylons-and-turbogears) of pylons tg and django.